# vmdk Recovery after migration from 3.5 to 4 and fallback tentative

Tags: vmware-esx, storage-area-network

Hy,

I've tryed to migrate some VM from my 3.5i environment to a brand new vSphere 4.0 U1.

The two platforms are running simultaneously, sharing the same SAN.

I Migrate my VM by stopping it, unregistering in vcenter (esx ver. 3.5, i call it esx3), register in vSphere (esx ver. 4, i call it esx4), and migrate upgrade virtual hardware before powering it up (First mistake). vMotion was enabled on esx4, seem to be a second mistake.

After a day or so, i encountred problems joigning the esx server (esx4) and decided to unregister my server for esx4 and fallback to esx3.

esx3 refused to boot, i supposed this was due to virtual hardware in Version 7 so i recreated a new VM pointing to the vmdk of the old VM.

Everithing seemed fine until i log into the server and discover that i was running on the original disk ith every snapshots ignored even those created on esx3.

I tried to reboot VM on esx4 but VM doesn't power up because "The parent virtual disk has been modified since the child was created".

I've got a copy of a later state of the drive but generated between two snapshots (ovf generated with canverter standalone) as a backup.

Do i have a chance to recover at least some files on the virtual drive or (as i tink) all is played, i've done enought mistakes for this time.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

i think this is a case for vmware support. you do have a subcription?

Answer (score 0):

Un-register the VM on all servers and download a full copy of the VM's data folder on the SAN, to your workstation.

Then, run it through VMWare converter standalone, back into your vSphere host.

This should get you back on your feet. if not, get on the phone to VMWare as they probably have a few tricks up the sleeve.

You actually encountered a bunch of common gotchas back-to-back on this one, including -

- VMs cannot be migrated or imported with outstanding snapshot. In some cases you can bring them across, but snapshots are automatically rolled-in during conversion.
- VMs should never be present in the inventory of more than 1 host at any time, to guard against situations where 2 hosts make simultaneous changes to the disk files.